# How to handle ordering on possible null list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generic-list

I need to return items from database but in descending order using LINQ.

This is my code:

```
var productItems = dbResult.ProductItems;
resultObj.productItems = productItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).ToList();
```

And I'm wondering in case `productItems` is null, if I apply `OrderByDescending` on possible null list, than code might break?

So how to properly handle this?

Comment: Maybe use the [`?.` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)?

Comment: @UweKeim can you write example? and can you please write what will happen if list is null but ? is applied. Thanks mate

Comment: Do you still want to display null's or remove them completely? You could use .Where() to remove the nulls.

Comment: if you run OrderbyDescending on a null list, it will simply return null

Comment: @MarcusLai how to test this

Comment: ```c#
List<AdditionalConfigBE> list = new List<AdditionalConfigBE>();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list.OrderByDescending(x => x.VolumeName).Select(x => x.SerialNumber)));
```
-> Prints null;

Comment: @MarcusLai Huuum? `null.OrderBy` will just throw a NRE, as will `OrderBy` on a list containing `null`-elements, at least if you use any of the elements members within the delegate passed to `OrderBy`.

Comment: @MarcusLai "if you run OrderbyDescending on a null list, it will simply return null" I have the feeling that op is asking about "'m wondering in case productItems is null," in this case he will get a nullreference exception

Comment: @MongZhu Yea mate, I'm wondering what would happen if list where I'm trying to apply Ordering on is acctually a null, would app throw an exception ?

Comment: yes it will throw

Comment: What would you like `resultObj.productItems` to be when `productItems` is `null`?

Comment: "So how to properly handle this?" it depends strongly on how you intend to use `resultObj.productItems` what is the role of this variable in the future processing of your programm

Comment: @Magnus null or maybe empty list?

Comment: You are right Mong Zhu.. if the productItems are null, you will get "Value cannot be null". Solution: 
```c#
List<AdditionalConfigBE> list = null;
var ou = list?.OrderByDescending(x => x.VolumeName);
```

Comment: @Roxy'Pro You have to choose, cant be both. Empty list might be easier to handle as you dont need to check for null later in your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are worried about `productItems` being `null`, simply check for it:

```
var productItems = dbResult.ProductItems;

if (productItems != null)
{
    resultObj.productItems = productItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to previously answered @robbpriestley:

If you don't want your ProductItems to be null, you can set an empty default value before ordering the list:

```
var productItems = dbResult.ProductItems;
if (productItems == null) {
    // Set whatever object it can be, such as
    productItems = new List<object>();
}

resultObj.productItems = productItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).ToList();
```

This way, you'll still end up with a list of items (or whatever entity you are working with), but it'll be empty.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you are talking about the list itself being null or an item of that list being null.

For list being null:

```
if (productItems != null)
{
    // your LINQ statement
}
```

For a possible item being null:

```
resultObj.productItems = productItems.Where(item => item != null).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).ToList();
```

However, this solution will ignore the null items of the list, which will not be in the `resultObj.productItems`

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick application to show how linq handles the sorting of null items. Like some of the other posters have suggested, you should be checking the list for null as well.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbResult = new Product
        {
            ProductItems = new List<ProductItem>
            {
                new ProductItem {CreatedDate = null, ProductName = "SomeProduct"},
                new ProductItem {CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ProductName = "SomeProduct2"},
                new ProductItem {CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow, ProductName = "SomeProduct3"}
            }
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Default Linq Ordering\n");

        var result = dbResult.ProductItems?.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).ToList();

        if (result != null)
        {
            foreach (var productItem in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Created Date: {1} \n", productItem.ProductName, productItem.CreatedDate);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Set null ordering to Datetime.Max\n");
        }

        result = dbResult.ProductItems?.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue).ToList();
        if (result != null)
        {
            foreach (var productItem in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Created Date: {1} \n", productItem.ProductName, productItem.CreatedDate);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public List<ProductItem> ProductItems { get; set; }
}
public class ProductItem {
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

The output is as follows:

> Default Linq Ordering
>
> SomeProduct3 Created Date: 12/2/2019 3:32:58 PM
>
> SomeProduct2 Created Date: 12/2/2019 10:32:58 AM
>
> SomeProduct Created Date:
>
> Set null ordering to Datetime.Max
>
> SomeProduct Created Date:
>
> SomeProduct3 Created Date: 12/2/2019 3:32:58 PM
>
> SomeProduct2 Created Date: 12/2/2019 10:32:58 AM

Answer (score -1):

If you above c# 6.0, you can use '?' operator to check for null
https://csharp.today/c-6-features-null-conditional-and-and-null-coalescing-operators/